# Having issue in JavaScript and PHP Code

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

I have a issue in my website (http://www.unlockgsmcodes.com/unlock-samsung/). My website was working fine few days ago then suddenly javascript is not working on my website. And php code is displayed in textboxes.

I developed my website in wordpress.
For php code i am using plugin "Allow PHP in Posts and Pages"

Comment: I'd search google for like "wordpress plugin Allow PHP in Posts and Pages stopped working"

Comment: and doing so you find its probably a difference in case for the table name after an upgrade, table wp_allowPHP_functions vs wp_allowphp_functions  https://wordpress.org/support/topic/plugin-allow-php-in-posts-and-pages-plugin-broke

Comment: This site is for programming questions. We are not here to debug your website for you.

Comment: Open console in Chrome and you will see:
Uncaught TypeError: jQuery(...).on is not a function - is the reason, why javascript is not working

Answer (score 1):

I am giving you couple of suggestions, have a look into them-

- If any `page template`, then check the `PHP` code. Mainly, start and end.
- If your page in `page` (dashboard>pages). I mean value printed using
  any plugin, then you deleted that plugin which was printing the value
  in your input field.
- If your page created using any `form plugin`. Then check the form plugin. Is it deactivated or not?
- Open console in Chrome and you will see: Uncaught TypeError:
  jQuery(...).on is not a function - is the reason, why javascript is
  not working (I am adding @deniskoronets comment here)
- Also use `$.noConflict()` or `jQuery.noConflict()` in your scripts

BTW, If you want best answer then you need to post more clue/information. 
Thanks